# autocomplete="off"and autocomplete="nope" is not working on chrome

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html

autocomplete is not working. I tried `autocomplete="off"`, `autocomplete="nope"` and `autocomplete="false"`. Still password and user name are showing in input text box

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.CustomerPasswordVM.OldPassword, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

Comment: how you are setting autocomplete of?

Comment: Not working (@Html.EditorFor(model => model.CustomerPasswordVM.OldPassword, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } }))

Answer (score 1):

From: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete

```
"off"
The browser is not permitted to automatically enter or select a value for this field.
It is possible that the document or application provides its own autocomplete feature,
or that security concerns require that the field's value not be
automatically entered.

    Note: In most modern browsers, setting autocomplete to "off" will not
prevent a password manager from asking the user if they would like to save
username and password information, or from automatically filling in those
values in a site's login form. See the autocomplete attribute and login 
fields.
```

Might this be your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Me too face the same problem , below code helped me.

```
  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CustomerPasswordVM.OldPassword, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @readonly= "readonly", @onfocus = "this.removeAttribute('readonly');" } })
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to do with autocomplete here. You see username and password option in respective textbox because you have saved it and asked Chrome to remember your password. This is newly implemented feature by Google that shows you password on first attempt. This feature has been enhanced in Chrome recently.

Answer (score 0):

try to use autocomplete="new-password" instead.